# how to set exact size of Elastic Search pagination in version 7.x?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic Search version 2.4 we can create a pagination with combination of `from` and `size` parameters in which `size` parameter is the exact size of search result documents.

But in Elastic Search 7.x `size` is the maximum size of search result documents. How can i create a pagination with exact size of search result in Elastic Search version 7.x?

Comment: `size = 1` returns more than 1 result?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: the only case where you get less than size results is when you hit the last page. There is no problem with from / size in elastic 7